# how to dont close python console after printing something

Tags: python, console

I have a code that print something in the console and after some works it clear console and print something new
so putting input() not works for me cause then it will wait user to do something but I want this printing stuff continue
how should I do it?
my code is exctracting a zip file and in the same time printing how much of it is done

```py
import threading
def Ex():
        from zipfile import ZipFile
        with ZipFile(my zip file) as zf:
            zf.extractall(path,pwd=my password)
def loading():
        done=False
        f=[]
        T=time.time()
        while not done:
                try:
                        f=os.listdir(my path)
                        clearConsole = lambda: os.system('cls' if os.name in ('nt', 'dos') else 'clear')
                        clearConsole()
                        print('Installing resources : '+str(int(len(f)/25*100))+'%')
                except:
                        pass
                if len(f)==25:
                        done=True
                time.sleep(5)
        time.sleep(10)
        sys.exit()
threading.Thread(target=Ex).start()
threading.Thread(target=loading).start()
```

Comment: you need to provide some part of your code, so we'd know how to help you.

Comment: I did it, can you help me ?

Comment: when does your console close? At the end? Or while working? something else?

Comment: when program is running console is gone , everytime I print ,it pops up for 0.001 seconds and then it go away again

Comment: but I want it to be open always cause user should see how much of extracting is done every moment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the cursor to the first of line, use [`\r`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return).

```py
f = os.listdir("path/to/file")
print('Installing resources : '+str(int(len(f)/25*100))+'%', end='\r')
```

[`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20system#os.system) does not run the commend in the current shell. It opens a new one. So you are just clearing a new shell every 5 seconds. If you really want to hold that, you can use `pause` command in Windows, which waits for user input and then close it. (`cls; pause`)